# SQL SERVER:A network-related or instance-specific error occurred

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I was using Microsoft SQL with asp.net MVC , it was working fine but today morning it gave me error :

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

I tried to Enable TCP/IP. I also started SQL in configuration manager but still cannot login to SQL Server 2014 using cloud server. It was working fine. I don't know what has happened to it.

Thanks

Comment: check if all services related to SQL Server are running fine

Comment: SQL Server Agent is not working ,It's giving error when i try to start it

Comment: The error says: The Sql Server service on local computer started and then stopped .Some Services start automatically if they are not in use by other services

Comment: If you're using SQL Express edition, that error is expected when trying to start the agent, that service has nothing to do with your connectivity issue though.

Answer (score 1):

There is a really good YouTube vid at the bottom of this web-page so you can rule out a few more things - failing that I would have the server rebooted.

[SQL Authority](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/)

Comment: where is youtube link?

Comment: @MasterSQL please don't just links to other sources without any content. If the YouTube video get deleted, your answer will become pretty useless.

Comment: I followed the video but still getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

In MS SQL Server Management Studio, have you checked the Properties of the SQL Server to ensure that Allow remote connections to the server is ticked?

If so then I would have to agree that it an on the Cloud Server rather than an issue with the SQL database.

Are you able to reboot the Cloud Server?

Comment: Hey can u tell me how to check the property?

Comment: i  dont know anything about cloud server else than its password and username

Answer (score 1):

MS SQL Studio 2014 doesn't work very well with SQL 2005 or older if you running an old database version

Answer (score 0):

You may want to ensure that the cloud server is allowing connections from your remote IP. It could be that your remote IP address has changed and you are no longer allowed access.

How to open the SQL database firewall for Microsoft Azure:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-configure-firewall-settings/

Comment: @Mah Mah That will depend on what cloud service you are using, Azure, AWS, etc

Comment: @Mah Mah please try the link in my post above